# Using csv.reader and csv.writer to write to the same file instead of different files?

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

How can I convert the following code to write to the same file instead of having to write to a new file?

```
import csv
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

def filter_data(data):
    for classname, group in itertools.groupby(data, itemgetter(2)):
        filtered_group = [line for line in group]
        new_count = len(filtered_group)
        for line in filtered_group:
            if line[5] == "Count":
                line[5] = "Counter"
            else:
                line[5] = new_count
            yield line

with open('main.csv', 'rb') as f_in, open('main1.csv', 'wb') as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerows(filter_data(reader))
```

My attemot if stringio what isn't working...

```
import csv
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter
import StringIO

def filter_data(data):
    for classname, group in itertools.groupby(data, itemgetter(2)):
        filtered_group = [line for line in group]
        new_count = len(filtered_group)
        for line in filtered_group:
            if line[5] == "Count":
                line[5] = "Counter"
            else:
                line[5] = new_count
            yield line

output = StringIO.StringIO()

with open('../main.csv', 'rb') as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    output.writelines(filter_data(reader))

contents = output.getvalue()
output.close()

with open('../main_test.csv', 'wb') as f_out: 
    f_out.writelines(contents)
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you write to a file while you're reading it?

Comment: @martineau It to go wrong, I'm asking for help to convert it so it doesn't write till after it's done what it needs to do or a way around this...

Comment: Just write it to a temporary file and afterwards delete the original and give its name to temporary one. If the file is small, you can write the temporary to memory using the `StringIO` module and then copy it from there to a real file afterwards.

Comment: @martinau I have no idea how to incorperate that into this tho...

Comment: Your attempt to use `StringIO` basically looks all right. I think the problem is that `filter_data()` is yielding `list` objects not strings and `writelines()` expects to be given a sequence of strings, plus they need to be terminated with a newline since you're trying to create a csv file. Try `yield ','.join(map(str, line)) + '\n'` and see if that helps. If not, add some sample data to your question for me to use and I'll look into it a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

#### code

```
import csv
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter
import StringIO

def filter_data(data):
    for classname, group in itertools.groupby(data, itemgetter(2)):
        filtered_group = [line for line in group]
        new_count = len(filtered_group)
        for line in filtered_group:
            if line[5] == "Count":
                line[5] = "Counter"
            else:
                line[5] = new_count
            yield ','.join(map(str, line)) + '\n'

output = StringIO.StringIO()

with open('../main.csv', 'rb') as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    output.writelines(filter_data(reader))

contents = output.getvalue()
output.close()

with open('../main.csv', 'wb') as f_out: 
    f_out.writelines(contents)
```

This should work :)